# Determine concentration

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How would I go about solving a problem that goes roughly as such?

```
Solution A: .1%
Solution B: .15%
```

`How many milliliters of each A & B are required to create 260 milliliters of a solution, C, that is .14%?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the following system:

1. $x+y = 260$
2. $0.1x+0.15y = (0.14)(260)$

Comment: I keep getting a negative answer. I think I'm doing something wrong... Wouldn't I multiply the top by either -.1 or -.15?

Comment: @Josh: The RHS of equation 2 should be 0.14*260.  Then you should be OK.  Can you explain why?